# NDEF Record and vCard data

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I am trying to write a vcard data in an NDEF Record using the Android NFC API. I am able to write a single URL or some text or phone numbers which are less than 46bytes in length. But when I try to write a vCard data which is more than this length say - 150 bytes - I am not able to store them in a card as the record length for this data is less. I am supposed to write this record accross multiple blocks or sectors.

I am doing something like,

```
byte[] vCardDataBytes = vCardData.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
byte[] vCardPayload = new byte[vCardDataBytes.length+1];
System.arraycopy(vCardDataBytes, 0, vCardPayload, 1, vCardDataBytes.length);
// vCardDataBytes[0] = (byte)0x00;
ndefRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA,"text/x-vcard".getBytes(),new byte[] {}, vCardPayload);
```

Can someone point me in a piece of code how I can write ndef records accross multiple sectors in Android ?. How do I specify them perhaps ?

thanks
Domnic

Comment: Can your tag handle 150 bytes in the first place?

Comment: I am using Mifare 1K and Ultralight.. they have enough memory.

Comment: Looks like this is handled by the lower level code, so you shouldn't need to split it your self. Try with the NXP Writer or similar app to see if it works with your tags. Also check what `getMaxSize()` returns.

Comment: MIFARE Ultralight cannot store 150 bytes

Answer (score 0):

writeNdefMessage should take care of all the splitting and writing for you. As "NFC Guy" pointed out, Mifare UL handles only about 64bytes of data. For Mifare1K, ensure that it is an unformatted card, and the blocks and sectors are not blocked by any previous application. Also,  you can find the maximum available size by [getMaxSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#getMaxSize%28%29) function.